# Java Security class to prevent you from terminating the code using exit(0)! in HackerRank

Tags: java, system.exit

Can anyone explain this code of HackerRank?

```
class DoNotTerminate {

    public static class ExitTrappedException extends SecurityException {    
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;
    }

    public static void forbidExit() {
       final SecurityManager securityManager = new SecurityManager() {
           @Override
           public void checkPermission(Permission permission) {
              if (permission.getName().contains("exitVM")) {
                  throw new ExitTrappedException();
              }
           }
       };
       System.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
    }
}
```

This following code will stop you from terminating the code using exit(0)!

Answer (score 3):

When a program tries to stop the JVM by calling `System.exit(...)`, then it first checks if this action is allowed by asking the security manager if the `exitVM` permission is granted.

The code you posted replaces the security manager with a custom security manager that will throw an `ExitTrappedException` when checking for the `exitVM` permission.

So, what happens is this:

1. User program calls `System.exit(...)`
2. The `System.exit(...)` method asks the security manager if the `exitVM` permission is allowed
3. The custom security manager throws an `ExitTrappedException`
4. `System.exit(...)` does not continue to stop the JVM, but passes the exception on the caller; the JVM keeps running